# Feach data from node.js backend - 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, authentication

I try standard fech data from db, but i have 401 problem, in postman work fine but when i try in react problem start.

Order.jsx file (REACT)

```
import { userRequest } from "../../requestMethods";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getOrders= async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get("orders");
        setOrders(res.data);
      } catch {}
    };
    getOrders();
  }, []);
  console.log(orders);`
```

requestMethods.js (REACT)

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))?.user;

const currentUser = user && JSON.parse(user).currentUser;

const TOKEN = currentUser?.accessToken;

console.log(TOKEN);

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  header: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

order.js (node)

```
const Order = require("../models/Order");
const {
  verifyToken,
  verifyTokenAndAuthorization,
  verifyTokenAndAdmin,
} = require("./verifyToken");

const router = require("express").Router();

router.get("/", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const orders = await Order.find();
    res.status(200).json(orders);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

When i login and console.log(TOKEN) is undefined but when i refresh page i see token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header` should be `headers` in `userRequest`:

```js
export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
//      ^ here
});
```

Comment: Thanks now i see result, but still at start is undefined and i need refresh page to see orders in console

Comment: I see, but if this fixes this 401 issue, you can mark it as accepted (there's no obligation to do so). Then you can create a new question and I can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

When you login, **localStorage.getItem("persist:root")** is no value. When you logined, **localStorage.getItem("persist:root")** has value.

and, This should be **headers**:

```
export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```